# Contao: Radio/Checkbox menu - Product attribute with Options Manager

Tags: php, contao

**Isotope e-commerce**

In the backend I've made some product attributes as Checkbox/Radio button menu and I've put the values using the Options Manager. 
Example: a field with name `filter_farben` (see picture: [settings for attribute field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roSnt.jpg))

On the frontend for the product if I use the generateAttribute('filter_farben') or check the raw data, I see only the ID of the field from the `tl_iso_attribute_option` table (34 for this - see second picture: [tl_iso_attribute_option table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LekKx.jpg)). 
How can I get the label of these field (In this case 'Natur')?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this strange thing. It doesn't seems to be the best one, but it's working:

```
   /** 
     * @param string    $id                 - returned id of attribute 
     * @param string    $field              - attribute alias 
     * @return string     $t[0]['label']   - attribute name 
     */ 
    function getAttributeNameByID($id, $field) { 
       $objAttribute=$GLOBALS['TL_DCA']['tl_iso_product']['attributes'][$field]; 
       $t = $objAttribute->getOptionsForProductFilter(array($id)); 
       return $t[0]['label']; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Still I am not sure what you want to achieve and where you are in your code. Let me just get the label for you:

```
    $objAttribute=$GLOBALS['TL_DCA']['tl_iso_product']['attributes']['filter_faben'];

    $strClass=$objAttribute->getFrontendWidget();

    $arrData = $GLOBALS['TL_DCA']['tl_iso_product']['fields']['filter_faben'];

    $arrField = $strClass::getAttributesFromDca($arrData, 'filter_faben', $arrData['default'], 'filter_faben', tl_iso_product, $objProduct);

    echo $arrField['label'];
```

So depending on where you are in the code, I don't know where you are going to get the `$objProduct`

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I think it was a misunderstanidng becuase of the 'field_name' variable. Check the updated question

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I think we're talking about two different things. I will try to explain as simple as I can: I am creating a product list, where I want to show the product name and the color (the color is the 'filter_farben' - type: Radio Button Menu, values created with Option Manager). In my custom list template, when I echo $this->generateAttribute("name"),i get the correct name. If I echo $this->generateAttribute("filter_farben"), I get numbers (34, 35, etc) which are the ID's of the selected color attribute. So except the ID's, I need 'Red', 'Natur', etc.=>selected options label

Comment: Did you check 'defined by customer'? in the screenshot its not.

Comment: But this shouldn't be defined by the customer. If check this, then the radio-button menu is hidden from the backend when I add a new product.